# Firebase won't log the app in. How can I make it running after a while?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've made a project back in 2021, worked ideally.
Now I need to make some changes, but it couldn't start at all.

The problem was in outdated packages and gradle.
So I've updated them and the app can't pass the Firebase initialization.
The app is starting normally, but when it's time to connect to the Firebase - it's just getting this mesage.

Interesting point is that when I'me running it on Ios emulator - it works well, the app is passing firebase init.
It's a case only with android.

[image: an error that I'm getting]

Here is an image mentioned a version of gradle:
[image]

I've tried evrything what I could find on internet: update gradle, plagins, flutter, check sha keys in firebase and google cloud console - nothing helped.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.